# MenuItem doesn't fire the MouseRightButtonDown event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, xaml

Don't have much to say, just can get into the event handler.

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" x:Name="x">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="_View" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Window" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var item in x.Items)
        {
            ((MenuItem)item).MouseRightButtonDown += MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown;
        }
    }

    void MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Can't get here
    }

}
```

p.s -  Same thing with MouseRightButtonUp,MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `MenuItem` handles the event and doesn't let it propagate. Is there something in particular you need to do? It's hard to give advice without telling us that. Have you considered using the `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` event instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to understand the relation between `MouseDown`event and the other mouse events, such as `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseRightButtonDown`. Please read the Remarks part at [UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown.aspx).

There suggests two possible solutions. The one of it is as following codes.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var item in x.Items)
        {
            var menuItem = ((MenuItem)item);
            //menuItem.MouseRightButtonDown += MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown;
            menuItem.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseRightButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown), true);
        }
    }

    void MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Handled:{0}\r\nOriginalSource: {1}\r\nSource:{2}\r\nRoutedEvent:{3}", 
                    e.Handled, e.OriginalSource, e.Source, e.RoutedEvent);
    }
}
```